# How to re-use steps in Feature file /Duplicate step definitions/

Tags: java, cucumber, gherkin, cucumber-java

I have a few Scenarios in a Feature file with repeatable steps ('I am on Login form' and 'click on login button'). Test failed with error `Duplicate step definitions in Steps.LoginSteps`. 
Is it possible to somehow to reuse duplicated steps?

```
Feature: LoginFeature

Scenario: Login with valid username and password
    Given I am on Login form
    And I enter valid username and password
    And click on login button
    Then I should see the main page


  Scenario: Login with invalid username and password
    Given  I am on Login form
    And I enter invalid email username and password
    And click on login button
    When modal error is displayed
    Then click on Ok button
    And I should see the login form
```

Comment: Have you created two methods with the same pattern matching for "I am on a Login form"? Can you add the relevant step definitions?

Comment: Exactly,  Steps definition file consisted duplicated methods too. I have removed duplicated methods in Steps definition file and it works fine now! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use Background for steps that are common for all the scenarios in the same feature (the goal is to avoid repetition)
Example:

```
Feature: LoginFeature

Background:

Given I am on Login form

Scenario: Login with valid username and password

    And I enter valid username and password
    And click on login button
    Then I should see the main page


  Scenario: Login with invalid username and password

    And I enter invalid email username and password
    And click on login button
    When modal error is displayed
    Then click on Ok button
    And I should see the login form
```

Also you could modify the step for button click in order to pass a parameter. This way you will have only one step for button click that you could use in different scenarios passing different parameter (login, Ok etc).

Example:

```
Click on "login" button
```

Comment: Thanks for the advice with Background. I've separated "Given I am on Login form" in the Background and it looks better!

Answer (score 2):

All steps are global and Cucumber will use the method with a matching regular expression.

The logic behind this is that if you use one way of describing your desired behaviour in two or more places, how can you expect this behaviour to be different in in different scenarios?

You give a perfect example with your login step. Do you expect to be on different login pages just because you are planning to verify a positive and a negative case? The answer is obviously no and therefore there is no need for more than one step implementation.

Next thing you might find is an urge to call a step from another step. Don't do that. Create a helper method that both steps call in this situation.

I try to keep my steps really short, one or two lines in most cases. I usually just delegate to a helper directly. This allows me to change abstraction level and go from translating arguments to a step to interacting with the system under test.

Comment: +1 for `Next thing you might find is an urge to call a step from another step. Don't do that. Create a helper method that both steps call in this situation.`